# Combining contextual filters for direct and indirect relationships

Tags: views, 8

We are trying to create a single view with multiple contextual filters. 
The goal is to display the content of type Alice related to content of type Bob.

The reference is set on type Alice using a direct entity reference to type Bob or via a shared taxonomy Charlie.

Hence, the setup is as follows:

`(1) Alice (Node) -enity reference-> Bob (Node)`

`(2) Alice (Node) -enity reference-> Charlie (Term) <-enity reference- Bob (Node)`

What we would like to achieve is to combine the direct relationsship (1) using the reference field as well as the indirect relationship (2) using the common taxonomy within one view and display all results matching **any** relationship.

So far we've tried making it work with *Content: ID* + *Content: Has taxonomy term ID* combined with the *Content: Bob* contextual filter.

We also added [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) to implemented this behavior, but this breaks the *Content: ID* + *Content: Has taxonomy term ID* combination.

Is there a way to set this up using contextual filters or is it easier to use hook_views_* and filters for this?

Comment: How exactly is Contextual OR breaking it? If you can create Views with only one of the Contextual filters, and a separate view with the second Contextual filter, and they both work independently, you can then just "merge" the configuration into one Display and use the Contextual OR option. Just to be clear, you want to list Alice nodes on Bob pages?